# Using a Mac harddrive on a PC

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I ordered a portable harddrive, a Western Digital USB3 500GB, to be exact. Upon receiving it, I realized that I had accidentally ordered one "For Mac". While the intention is to use this on a PC as a bootable utility disk running Arch Linux, this strikes me as odd, because I was under the impression that a USB drive is a USB drive, without any limitations to a specific architecture for use.

My question then is:
- Are there any hardware-related differences related to a USB drive specifically "made for Mac", as the drive says?
- Can I still use it on a PC somehow?

Note:
I did try it briefly on Win7, and it seems to register, except the factory-setup partitions do not register with a drive letter. Is it therefore safe to conclude that from the looks of it, the only difference is the filesystem and partitioning scheme installed from the factory?

Comment: From my experience you are correct the only difference is the factory partition filesystem and possibly the drivers that are shipped with the drive if there was any. Delete those partitions and the drive is just a normal USB drive.

Comment: Sometimes "for Mac" hardware differs from "for PC" versions in unimportant details like the color of the device. Other than that possibility, for a USB hard disk, I'd expect there to be no differences in the hardware, just in the partitioning and/or filesystem used as delivered. Of course, you can change both of those yourself. I haven't checked recently, but in the past, "for Mac" hardware also sometimes carried a price premium. If that's true of your disk, you may have wasted a few bucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be able to easily delete the existing partition and replace it with an NTFS partition.

The problem is Windows doesn't recognize the type of partition on the drive without additional software which you would only want to bother with if you actually wanted to share data with a Mac.

It's the other direction, but I regularly purchase a variety of WD passport drives in whatever format is available and cheap and just repartition them for my Mac.